# How do I get time of launch of a running process?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the time of launch of a running process. Is it possible to do in Windows, and how please?

Comment: This may be a start: [PROCESS_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145563.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GetProcessTimes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Use [GetCurrentProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the current process.

One of its arguments (`lpCreationTime`) is a pointer to a `FILETIME` struct which gets filled in with the time the process was created.

You can then use [FileTimeToSystemTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the `FILETIME` struct to a `SYSTEMTIME` struct which has calendar day/month/year and hour/minute/second fields.

```
HANDLE hCurrentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

FILETIME creationTime;
FILETIME exitTime;
FILETIME kernelTime;
FILETIME userTime;

GetProcessTimes(hCurrentProcess, &creationTime,
    &exitTime, &kernelTime, &userTime);

SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&creationTime, &systemTime);

// systemTime now holds the calendar date/time the
// current process was created
```

Comment: How do I to display its value please?

Comment: @user3319426 As console output? As a message box? As a text label in a window? An MFC window or one created with the native Win32 API? Are you perhaps in over your head if you don't know how to display a value from a program?

Comment: @user3319426 `printf()`? `std::cout`?

Comment: maybe `TEXT("%s");` ?

Comment: can we convert it to string ?